# .htaccess to control dot in the URL

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have .htaccess as below:

## Don't rewrite any URIs ending with a file extension (ending with .[xxxx])

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,5}$

This does not allow dot in the URL. Can you suggest change so that dot can be allowed in the URL ?

Answer (score 0):

The dot is a special character in regular expressions that matches any character. You should escape it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,5}$
```

This works fine. You can play around with it on [an online htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: I need to accept .dot in the URLs. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: That was my original .htaccess but it is not working. Still getting 404 errors with dot.

Comment: Here you have the proof: http://www.ultraimg.com/image/o7w4,  http://www.ultraimg.com/image/o7wB It will rewrite urls without extension, but possibly with dots, and it won't rewrite urls with extension. If you have 404 errors, they must be coming from elsewhere.